# Merging pairs of TIFF files in a directory

Tags: images, imagemagick, image-manipulation

For example, say a given directory has 1000 TIFF files named `sample1.TIFF`, `sample2.TIFF`, etc., all the way to `sample1000.TIFF`. I want to merge each pair of files: `sample1.TIFF` and `sample2.TIFF` are merged into `sample1_2.TIFF`, `sample3.TIFF` and `sample4.TIFF` are merged into `sample3_4.TIFF`, and so on. When finished I will have 500 merged TIFF files remaining. How can I do this with Unix/Perl/AIX scripting?

Answer (score 2):

For merging the TIFFs, you can use [**tiffcp**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11135991/2089697). For your example, you can write a simple loop in `Perl`:

```
for ($i= 1; $i<= 100; $i+=2) { 
    $j = $i + 1;    
    system("tiffcp sample$i.TIFF sample$j.TIFF sample$i\_$j.TIFF");
}
```

**Update:**

If there is no sequence on the TIFF files, i.e. in place of sample1.tif, sample2.tif, you have abc.tiff, def.tiff..and so on and you need to merge first 2 tiff in folder as per timestamp, then you can do the following:

Sort the TIFF files by **timestamp** using `ls -lt`, and then extract the TIFF filenames from the output. You can either do this using `awk` (see below) or if you have access to `vim`, then you can use `Ctrl-v` to remove the unwanted columns from each line of the output.

`ls -lt | awk '$9 ~ "TIFF$" { print $9 } ' > sorted_TIFFs.list`

Once you have the list of sorted TIFF files, you can traverse through them and run `tiffcp` using a simple `Perl` script. This script takes the `sorted_TIFFs.list` you generated in the previous step as the command line input.

```
#!/bin/perl

$file=$ARGV[0];
open FILE, $file || die "Invalid filename";

while ($line=<FILE>) {
    chomp($line);
    $file1 = $line;
    if ($line = <FILE>)
    {
        chomp ($line);
        $file2 = $line;
        $prefix= $file1;
        $prefix =~ s/\.TIFF//; #to avoid a.TIFF_b.TIFF
        system("tiffcp $file1 $file2 $prefix\_$file2\n");
    } else {
       print "No matching TIFF file, odd number of total files.\n";
       exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is no sequence on the TIFF files, i mean in place of sample1.tif, sample2.tif, it will like abc.tiff, def.tiff..and so on. If i need to merge first 2 tiff in folder as per timestamp, then how could i achieve this?

Comment: Updated the solution, let me know if anything is unclear.